# How do I serialize square brackets containing two fields in angular?

Tags: angularjs, json, serialization

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here goes:

I need to serialize my json into this:

```
  "Request": {
    "claims": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
$scope.user.Request.claims = [];
$scope.user.Request.claims.id = 1;
$scope.user.Request.claims.name = 'someclaim';
```

it serializes to:

```
Request":{"claims":[{}]}
```

I'm probably missing something basic here (hopefully).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.user.Request.claims is an array.

So instead of these

```
$scope.user.Request.claims.id = 1;
$scope.user.Request.claims.name = 'someclaim';
```

Those might help you:

```
$scope.user.Request.claims[0].id = 1;
$scope.user.Request.claims[0].name = 'someclaim';
```

Comment: Had to update my declaration to $scope.user.Request.claims = [{}]; to avoid a null ref, but it's working now, thanks!